# Appending session values to an Array in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to deal with sessions in Java. I need to increase a view value everytime someone goes to a new page, but then only increase it once per user per session. At the moment the code below does not do that, it increases it all the time. I think the problem might be that everytime a page is loaded, the arraylist is made new again? I'm not sure how to deal with this. As the objects don't stay in the array after a refresh.

Code to deal with the session and try to increment the count
       // get the name of the picture
        session.setAttribute("pictureName", pictureName);

```
    // create a list of objects that will store all the pages a user visits
    ArrayList<String> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<String>();

    // make a image_id variable but assign it the value of the page name
    String image_id = (String) session.getAttribute("pictureName");

    // go and compare each element in the list, to the id.
    // This should NOT match on the first viewing since it's the first time the user
    // visits the page
    // this should then increment the view count
    if (Utilities.isFirstVisit(listOfObjects, image_id) == true) {
        Utilities.IncreaseCount(out, pictureName);
        out.println("its worked");

    } else {
        // if a match is found then the user has already visited this page
        // therefore don't increment the view count for the love of christ
        out.println("A match was found");

    }
```

Method that is called to add or not add the object to the array list

```
public static boolean isFirstVisit(ArrayList <String> listOfObjects,
            String image_id) {
        System.out.println(listOfObjects);
        System.out.println(image_id);

    if(listOfObjects.contains(image_id)) {
        System.out.println("It does contain");
        System.out.println(image_id);
        return false;
    }

    else { 
        listOfObjects.add(image_id);
        System.out.println("It does not contain");
        System.out.println(image_id);
        return true;
        }
    }
```

Method to increase the views

```
//Increase the access count on the picture
    public static void IncreaseCount(PrintWriter out, String pictureName) {

        Connection con = null;
        try { // Connect to the database
            con = openConnection(out);
        } catch (Exception e) { // Failed to open the connection
            out.println("<P>" + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        try {

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String query;
            ResultSet rs1;

            query = "UPDATE Statistics SET AccessCount = AccessCount + 1 WHERE PictureNo = (SELECT PictureNo FROM Pictures WHERE FileName = '"
                    + pictureName + "')";

            stmt.executeUpdate(query);

            stmt.close();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            out.println("<P>SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

#### #

Updated justs updates one picture per session, rather than all visited pictures per session

```
   if(session.getAttribute("myVisitedPages") == null) {
           ArrayList<String> listOfPages = new ArrayList<String>();

           session.setAttribute("myVisitedPages", listOfPages);

            if (Utilities.isFirstVisit(listOfPages, pictureName) == true) {
                Utilities.IncreaseCount(out, pictureName);
                out.println("its worked");

            } 
       }
```

Comment: Are you storing this hit counter in memory or in a database somewhere?

Comment: Yes on a mysql database. I will update the OP with the method I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store the list of visited pages in the session.

Here is the flow:

1. Try get attribute from session of "myVisitedPages"
2. First time it will be `null`. Create a `new ArrayList()`, attach it to the session by using `setAttribute`, and add the first page id to it.
3. Second time onwards, the list will be available as a session attribute, and you can get that list, and check inside that list.

(BTW, I am not sure why your currently visited page id needs to be there in the session.)

After update. The If's shouldn't be nested:

```
  ArrayList<String> listOfPages = session.getAttribute("myVisitedPages");
  if(listOfPages == null) {
       listOfPages = new ArrayList<String>();

       session.setAttribute("myVisitedPages", listOfPages);
   }

   if (Utilities.isFirstVisit(listOfPages, pictureName) == true) {
       Utilities.IncreaseCount(out, pictureName);
       out.println("its worked");
   }
```

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. I've updated my OP with code to show what i've tried. Currently there is some improvement but it now just updates one picture per session.

Comment: It's difficult to debug with pieces of code. And even more tough without console output. I'm guessing you are getting a new session each time. Try printing the session object itself. Maybe it will show a new hash code each time.

Comment: Or you might always be getting the same pictureName attribute. You can try logging that also.

Comment: Thankyou so much for the reply. So i've printed out both attributes. But the sessionId is remaining the same for the whole thing as you would expect and the pictureName attribute is printing out the right pictureName for each page.

Comment: @JohnDoi2021 You missed a small thing. Updated my answer.

Comment: you god dam legend. This has been 6 hours of my life. Thankyou so much.

Comment: I just need to find some way of including it with a way of handling cookies being turned off.

Comment: Glad to help :) And, that's a big pain.. URL rewriting to make session work without cookies.

Answer (score -1):

Ok well from  what i understand u want  too increment
the counter  every  time there  is a new  visit  too the web
view
If so.
Declare  an

```
HttpSession obj = request.getSession();
obj.setSessionAttribute("image_id", null);
  
  If (obj.getAttribute("image_id") == null){
     Write_to_db();
     string value="user counted";
     obj.setSessionAttribute("image_id", value); 
     }
```

Comment: Please spend a minute to see how to properly format your code (and text).